# DAX Query to get a specific range of rows

Tags: range, dax

How can I create a DAX query that retrieves rows from a given range in that order. Let's say I want the rows from row 1000 to row 2000. There is no unique id in my database. Should I add one, or is it possible without it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't distinguish a filter to create the subset of rows you are targeting then I would use a unique ID. I have not come across anything in DAX that allows to select rows in your powerpivot data set. If there isn't anything unique about the data you are targeting then I imagine you would need a unique ID.

i.e. I normally have column values I can filter with to target or create the subset of data I want to use.

I hope I am wrong and there is a way and look forward to someone posting a way.